# Unexpected Doctrine ORM Behavior During Upgrade: shcema upate trying to delete Foreign Keys and Recreate in One-to-Many Relationship with Join Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5.4

I am currently in the process of upgrading my project from Doctrine ORM version 2.13 to version 2.17. During the upgrade, I've noticed a behavior change in the SQL generated by Doctrine schema update and migration diff when updating the database schema.

its trying to do:

```
ALTER TABLE email_application_lookup DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_457AE1CCA832C1C9;
ALTER TABLE email_application_lookup DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_457AE1CC3E030ACD;
-- Other unrelated statements
ALTER TABLE email_application_lookup ADD CONSTRAINT FK_457AE1CCA832C1C9 FOREIGN KEY (email_id) REFERENCES email (id);
ALTER TABLE email_application_lookup ADD CONSTRAINT FK_457AE1CC3E030ACD FOREIGN KEY (application_id) REFERENCES application (id);
```

This behavior is unexpected and seems to introduce unnecessary overhead. I specifically observed this issue with tables that have a one-to-many relationship using a join table. I have reviewed the release notes for versions 2.14, 2.15, 2.16, and 2.17 but couldn't find any specific mention of changes related to foreign key handling in one-to-many relationships with join tables.

i have changed the syntax of these tables as mentioned in the release notes
i changed from : -

```
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(
        targetEntity: '\App\Entity\Email',
        fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY',
        cascade: ['persist']
    )]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(
        name: 'email_liability_lookup',
        joinColumns: [
            new ORM\JoinColumn(
                name: 'loan_id',
                referencedColumnName: 'id'
            ),
            new ORM\InverseJoinColumn(
                name: 'email_id',
                referencedColumnName: 'id'
            ),
        ]
    )]
```

to

```
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'email_liability_lookup')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'loan_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'email_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: '\App\Entity\Email', fetch: 'EXTRA_LAZY', cascade: ['persist'])]
```

but still it is trying to delete and create foreign keys again